# problem with use delimiter in scanner class

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

```
    try {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));

    Formatter out = new Formatter("text1.txt");
    in.useDelimiter(",");
    int num = in.nextInt();//this line throws null exception
    for(int i = 0; i < num && in.hasNext(); i++)
    {

        out.format("%s","#string \n" + i );

        out.format("%s", in.next());


    }
    out.close();
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
```

the input is:

```
    4
hello,my,name,is
```

4 is number of words.
the out put must be:

```
hello my name is
```

but it trow exeption with `null` error.
what is problem?

Comment: Which line of the code causes that `null` error?

Comment: Your code currently has more closing braces than opening ones... please change it so that it will compile properly, and post the stack trace, noting any lines which are referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a proper regular expression in the`useDelimiter`method. The following code should work:

```
try {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
    Formatter out = new Formatter("text1.txt");
    in.useDelimiter(",|\n|\r\n|\\s+");
    int num = in.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < num && in.hasNext(); i++)
        out.format("string # %d is: [%s]\n", i, in.next() );
    out.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.print("Exception: " + e);
}
```

#### Output

For the given input

```
4
hello,my,name,is
```

it outputs:

```
string # 0 is: [hello]
string # 1 is: [my]
string # 2 is: [name]
string # 3 is: [is]
```

Comment: @mehdi: I think you are a programmer and you can modify the code that way it will takes the input from a file.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Courteaux :) @mehdi I edited code to use file instead of System.in and System.out. But as Martin said you could have just replaced it easily as well, intent of my code was to show you how to use proper regex in the `useDelimiter` method.

Comment: this code throws this exception:**Exception: java.util.InputMismatchException** in same line

Comment: Do you have spaces before 4 in in your text.txt?

Comment: See my edit or try new regex: `in.useDelimiter(",|\n|\r\n|\\s+");`

Comment: I edited my answer to take care of spaces as well. If you put spaces again and try latest code or `in.useDelimiter(",|\n|\r\n|\\s+");` it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that as you specify that the delimiter is a comma, the newline character is not a delimiter any more.

Change your file to 4,hello,my,name,is and it should work.

Comment: I understood that and I was explaining what happened and did not mention anything about not reading from a file. If you cannot change the files, then change your parsers to match both \n and , to be delimiters.

Comment: this code throws this exception:**Exception: java.util.InputMismatchException** in same line

Comment: sorry my purpose was @anubhava